# srch.png not showing in Firefox but shows in Chrome

Tags: php

```
<form id="searchForm" onsubmit="return validsearch()" action="search.php" method="post" name="searchForm">
  <input class="nnew_ttxtbx" type="text" name="searchf">
  <input width="55" type="image" height="21" border="0" align="right" src="images/srch.png">
</form>
```

This is my code. Firefox shows the submit query for png img place, however, Chrome shows it correctly. What could be wrong?

Comment: Could you please provide more context? You are referring to a png img which is not present in your code example. Please include the JS functions and the PNG but you are referring to.

Comment: Above example works in my FF. Notice it is aligned right. Verify noting is rendered on top of it

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use the regular [`<button>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/button) tag?

```
<form id="searchForm" onsubmit="return validsearch()" action="search.php" method="post" name="searchForm">
  <input class="nnew_ttxtbx" type="text" name="searchf">
  <button type="submit" style="width: 55px; height: 21px; border: none;">
    <img src="images/srch.png" />
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: @SandyLee_user53167 — Not a typo.

Comment: @user1898114 I wish I could have customers like yours I wouldn't need to care about the DOM. :(

Comment: @Quentin Was that intentional?